# Craft 4 - Mul­ti-Fac­tor Authen­ti­ca­tion

Tags: craft4

I am looking to implement Mul­ti-Fac­tor Authen­ti­ca­tion on Craft Admin.

In this article, it seems to be added to Craft 4 :

https://craftquest.io/articles/what-new-features-are-in-craft-cms-4#multi-factor-authentication

But can't see any information in roadmap or documentation.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know (and can tell based on the [Changelog](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/CHANGELOG.md) and the lack of docs around an MFA feature) - that hasn't made it into Craft core yet. The blog post you referenced was written well before Craft 4 was actually released and is a list of features that were announced as planned for Craft 4, but obviously that's not a guarantee that all of those made it (I think P&T's goal was, and will be going forward for future major releases, to get Craft 4 launched on time regardless of whether it contained all the features they had hoped to ship).

In the meantime, you could probably utilize [this plugin](https://plugins.craftcms.com/two-factor-authentication) until MFA is a built-in feature.

Comment: Thanks Jalen, I saw the plugin Two Factor Authentication, but seems to have lot of issues, and I want to be sure to not block my team.
I saw also a discussion here, no news from june 2022 : https://github.com/craftcms/cms/discussions/8453

Comment: Last I heard, the 2FA/MFA effort has been shelved. The Craft team is looking into SSO support instead, but I don't think a specific release has been signalled for it.